# Listview with search and onclick doesnt get the right position when clicked after the filter

Tags: java, android, eclipse, arraylist

So here's my code. I put the topic name, topic codes, and topic results in an arraylist. The problem is, for example i have A (Position 0), B (Position 1),and  C (Position 2). When I search for B and clicked it, the app will go to Position 0 which is for A.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_c);

    ctopics = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.clistView);
    csearch = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.CSearch);

    ctitle = new ArrayList<Ctitle>();



    ctopics.setAdapter(cAdapter);
    ctitle.add(new Ctitle("Swap Two Numbers",
            "#include <iostream>\nusing namespace std;\nint main(){\nint a = 5, b = 10, temp;\ncout << ''Before swapping.'' << endl;\ncout << ''a = '' << a << '', b = '' << b << endl;\n\ntemp = a;\na = b;\nb = temp;\n\ncout << ''\nAfter swapping.'' << endl;\ncout << ''a = '' << a << '', b = '' << b << endl;\n\nreturn 0;\n}",
            "Before swapping.\na = 5, b = 10\n\nAfter swapping.\na = 10, b = 5"));
    ctitle.add(new Ctitle("While Loop",
            "#include <iostream>\nusing namespace std;\nint main(){\nint a = 10;\nwhile( a < 15 ){\ncout << ''value of a: '' << a << endl;\na++;\n}\nreturn 0;\n",
            "value of a: 10\nvalue of a: 11\nvalue of a: 12\nvalue of a: 13\nvalue of a: 14"));


    ArrayList<String> names = new ArrayList<String>();

    for (int i=0; i<ctitle.size(); i++)
    {
        names.add(ctitle.get(i).getTopic());
    }

    cAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(CActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, names);
    ctopics.setAdapter(cAdapter);



    ctopics.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() 
    {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) 
        {
            Intent intent = new Intent(CActivity.this, Cdisplay.class);
            intent.putExtra("info", ctitle.get(position));
            startActivityForResult(intent, 0);

        }

    });
```

Any help would be much appreciated, thank you!

Edit:

public class Ctitle implements Serializable {

```
/**
 * 
 */
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

private String topic,code,result;

public Ctitle(String topic,String code,String result)
{
    super();
    this.topic=topic;
    this.code=code;
    this.result=result;

}

public String getTopic() {
    return topic;
}

public void setTopic(String topic) {
    this.topic = topic;
}

public String getCode() {
    return code;
}

public void setCode(String code) {
    this.code = code;
}

public String getResult() {
    return result;
}



public void setResult(String result) {
    this.result = result;
}
```

}

Comment: Try `cAdapter.getItem(position)` instead of `ctitle.get(position)`.

Comment: Im having "The method getItem(int) is undefined for the type ArrayList<Ctitle>"

Comment: Call the method on an `ArrayAdapter` not on an `ArrayList`. eg: `cAdapter.getItem(position)`

Comment: There's no error in the codes. But it crashes when i click a topic in my listview. Logcat gave me this error "Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to com.example.javactutorial.Ctitle"

Comment: The `getItem(...)` method returns a `String` and you're casting that to a `Ctitle`. The last `ArrayAdapter` you set to the list is the one which is using the `names` list which is filled with `String`s.

Comment: I edit the question and put my Ctitle. What should i add or edit?

Comment: You'll need to create a custom adapter in order to use an `ArrayList<Ctitle>` object.

Comment: Thank you! Will search on how to create one

Answer (score 0):

```
ctopics.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() 
{

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) 
    {
        Intent intent = new Intent(CActivity.this, Cdisplay.class);
        intent.putExtra("info", (String)ctopics.getItemAtPosition(position));
        startActivityForResult(intent, 0);

    }

});
```

Comment: IM having an error "The method getItemAtPosition(int) is undefined for the type ArrayList<Ctitle>"

Comment: see my edited answer. i have changed it from ctitle to ctopics.